# jQuery Ajax is adding timestamp on dates automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

i have mysql query which return some data with dates. When i am requesting ajax request it add timestamp into my response.

Is there any way so it didn't added timestamp automatically on responses.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/getdata",
  type: "POST",
  data: { },
  success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(result)
  }
});
```

```php
var query = "SELECT SUM(`id`) as `total`,DATE(`log_date`) as `log_date` from `mytable` Group by `log_date`"
```

This is my response which is adding `T18:30:00.000Z` to end of the dates:

```
[
  RowDataPacket { total: 1, log_date: 2020-11-09T18:30:00.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { total: 10, log_date: 2020-11-10T18:30:00.000Z },
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: @tonoslfx i have added the code..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a jQuery issue, it's a mix of JS and PHP and how you're storing your date values in the database.

JS Date objects ***have*** to contain a time value as well. There is no date-only data type. As such your response from PHP is interpreted with the date you return and a time of `00:00:00` is added to it to maintain validity.

I can see from your profile that you are in India so your timezone offset is +5:30, hence JS assumes the date is in your local format and tries to convert it to UTC by subtracting 5:30 from it. Therefore the resulting date is 1 day before the actual value at `16:30:00`.

To fix this I would suggest you return your dates in full [ISO8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), including time and offset, so there is no ambiguity that JS attempts to overcome.

Comment: var newdate = new Date('2020-11-09T18:30:00.000Z').toISOString().split("T")[0]; solved my issue

Comment: Glad it helped you find a solution